# Send image from flask to js file

Tags: javascript, python, flask

On one hand, i created two JS files, with the 1st one, i can take picture from camera, and the second, detect the object(based on a machine learning model developed in python), on the other hand, i created a flask server. for now, i can take the picture from 1st JS and send it to flask where it's stored in a directory.
My question is, while i can send the picture from 1st JS to flask, how can i send the same picture from flask to 2nd JS with some details like the details about the picture's object that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand your question completely, but I solved a file upload / download scenario by reading the following example:

[https://github.com/dcrosta/flask-pymongo/blob/master/flask_pymongo/**init**.py](https://github.com/dcrosta/flask-pymongo/blob/master/flask_pymongo/__init__.py)

```
from flask.globals import current_app
<flask_restplus_get_method>
response = current_app.response_class(
    db_obj.screenshot,
    mimetype=db_obj.screenshot_mimetype,
    direct_passthrough=True,
)
response.content_length = len(screenshot)
response.last_modified = db_obj.screenshot_modified
response.set_etag(md5(screenshot).hexdigest())
response.cache_control.public = False
response.make_conditional(request)
return response
<flask_restplus_get_method>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your image to 'base64' string format in js file then send it over to flask server.Then you need to decode that 'base64' string to image in flask/server code then feed it to your ML model.